# Organizing data in a vector to be assigned to certain columns in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a vector that I scraped from this website, https://mountwashingtonavalanchecenter.org/hermit-lake-snow-plot-data-all/ I would like to take the vector which currently has each day's data accounting for 12 elements and then the next day, so 1-12 is a day then 13-24 and so on.

I tried finding a css selector in the html that would allow me to select data off the table by columns and not the whole table, however I couldn't find and efficient way to do this as I hade to define the column number as well as the row number for each specififc piece of data. using data.frame() on the vector showed me the data in order with NULL values represented with " ". I would like the data.frame to look like this:

```
             Date HN24 HN24.SWE. Density HST Total Air.Temp Max.T Min.T      Sky Precip Comments
1 02/08/19\n05:25    0       0.6      NA   0   165      3.5   3.5    -2 Overcast   Rain       NA
```

But the vector currently looks like this:

```
> whole_table
  [1] "02/08/19\n05:25"  "  0 CM"           "  0.6 MM"         ""                 
"0CM"             
  [6] "165 CM"           "3.5 C"            "3.5 C"            "-2.0 C"           
"Overcast"        
 [11] "Rain"             ""                 "02/07/19\n05:25"  "  1 CM"           
"  12.9 MM"       
 [16] " 19%"             "1CM"              "169 CM"           "-1.5 C"           
"0.0 C"           
 [21] "-10.0 C"          "Scattered"        "No precipitation" "View"             
"02/06/19\n05:28" 
 [26] "  0 CM"           "  0.9 MM"         ""                 "0CM"              
"168 CM"          
 [31] "-10.0 C"          "6.0 C"            "-10.5 C"          "Clear"            
"No precipitation"
 [36] ""
```

Is there any package or function that could help me organize the data i have in my vector to be assigned to the correct columns in a data.frame?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you what you want?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

df <- read_html("https://mountwashingtonavalanchecenter.org/hermit-lake-snow-plot-data-all/") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  flatten_df()
df
#> # A tibble: 50 x 12
#>    Date  HN24  `HN24W(SWE)` `Density (%)` HST   Total `Air T` `T Max`
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 "02/~ Trace Trace        ""            NC    201 ~ -14.5 C -9.0 C 
#>  2 "02/~ Trace Trace        ""            Trace 204 ~ -16.5 C -9.5 C 
#>  3 "02/~ 13 CM 10.7 MM      12%           13CM  205 ~ -10.0 C -2.0 C 
#>  4 "02/~ Trace 0.1 MM       ""            30CM  195 ~ -7.0 C  -5.0 C 
#>  5 "02/~ 11 CM 6.5 MM       10%           NC    196 ~ -14.0 C -6.0 C 
#>  6 "02/~ 24 CM 29.0 MM      17%           NC    187 ~ -8.0 C  -7.0 C 
#>  7 "02/~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 ~ -16.0 C -13.0 C
#>  8 "02/~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 ~ -15.0 C -14.0 C
#>  9 "02/~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 ~ -19.0 C -17.0 C
#> 10 "02/~ Trace Trace        ""            NC    164 ~ -18.0 C 6.0 C  
#> # ... with 40 more rows, and 4 more variables: `T Min` <chr>, Sky <chr>,
#> #   Precip <chr>, Comments <chr>
```

To see the table try, `View(df)`.

And since this looks like it has multiple pages of results, you may want to scrape all the pages like this:

```r
base_url <- "https://mountwashingtonavalanchecenter.org/hermit-lake-snow-plot-data-all/?frm-page-11115="

make_tbl <- function(pg_nbr) {
  read_html(paste0(base_url, pg_nbr)) %>%
    html_table() %>%
    flatten_df()
}

1:5 %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map(~ make_tbl(.)) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'page_number')

# A tibble: 226 x 13
   page_number Date       HN24  `HN24W(SWE)` `Density (%)` HST   Total  `Air T` `T Max` `T Min` Sky    Precip    Comments
   <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <chr>        <chr>         <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   
 1 1           "02/18/19~ Trace Trace        ""            NC    201 CM -14.5 C -9.0 C  -16.5 C Overc~ Snow      ""      
 2 1           "02/17/19~ Trace Trace        ""            Trace 204 CM -16.5 C -9.5 C  -16.5 C Clear  No preci~ ""      
 3 1           "02/16/19~ 13 CM 10.7 MM      12%           13CM  205 CM -10.0 C -2.0 C  -10.0 C Overc~ No preci~ ""      
 4 1           "02/15/19~ Trace 0.1 MM       ""            30CM  195 CM -7.0 C  -5.0 C  -15.0 C Overc~ No preci~ ""      
 5 1           "02/14/19~ 11 CM 6.5 MM       10%           NC    196 CM -14.0 C -6.0 C  -15.0 C Overc~ Snow      ""      
 6 1           "02/13/19~ 24 CM 29.0 MM      17%           NC    187 CM -8.0 C  -7.0 C  -16.0 C Overc~ Snow      View    
 7 1           "02/12/19~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 CM -16.0 C -13.0 C -18.0 C Clear  No preci~ ""      
 8 1           "02/11/19~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 CM -15.0 C -14.0 C -20.0 C Clear  No preci~ ""      
 9 1           "02/10/19~ 0 CM  0 MM         ""            0CM   164 CM -19.0 C -17.0 C -19.0 C Clear  No preci~ ""      
10 1           "02/09/19~ Trace Trace        ""            NC    164 CM -18.0 C 6.0 C   -18.0 C Overc~ Snow      View    
# ... with 216 more rows
```

Finally, to make the `read_html` function more robust, you may want to modify it with `purrr::possibly` so that it fails gracefully. For example, there is no `page = 6` (at least not yet), but the following will still "work":

```r
possible_read <- possibly(read_html, otherwise = NULL)

make_tbl <- function(pg_nbr) {
  possible_read(paste0(base_url, pg_nbr)) %>%
    html_table() %>%
    flatten_df()
}

1:6 %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map(~ make_tbl(.)) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'page_number')
```

Comment: Yes, I took that and used as.data.frame(df) and now the data is just like I wanted, Thank you JasonAizkalns